# Switching from MongoDB to Cassandra?

Tags: php, mongodb, cassandra

I am currently working on a 'simple' social network style in PHP. I call it 'simple' because it's not the classic example-type website; I just try and keep it as simple is possible;

So I *basically* am on MongoDB and have a two collection structure: the users table, which is something like

```
{ user:'test', pass:'123456', name:'foobar', info:'hello' }
```

and a posts table:

```
{ user:'test', message:'this is a test post' }
```

I simplified it all to make or more readable at first sight.

As said I am using MongoDB currently, working great and all but, I just read a bit about Cassandra and was wondering if it could be a better choice, given its simpler scaling features (I could basically do it myself instead of having to rely on MongoLab or MongoHQ);

But I am not sure if this could be a good idea as I am making use of dynamic queries.

Messaging and Relationships are not taken into consideration, I am using Redis for this; The switch would only be related to the registration of the users, search, and their posts.

Any ideas if I should keep with Mongo, or if I could *consider* a change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do MongoDB yourself easily too and you would have the exact same benefits/short comings as with Cassandra. I would consider changing your search to a search tech if your using MongoDB but apart from that I just think that maybe it is time for you to setup your own MongoDB.

Comment: I am currently, but only in development, I honestly am not confident enough to have it in production for security issues.

Comment: What security issue concerns have you got? I mean you use MongoHQ and MongoLabs so I am unsure what security issues you could be thinking of

Comment: I am concerned about security when *not* using those services. sorry I am not native and wasn't really clear on that reply.

Comment: Can you be specific? To have security concerns you must have a scenario or something that concerns you with a vector of attack? I mean MongoLabs and MongoHQ use built in security features of MongoDB, the only difference, as would occur with Cassandra as well, is that they have configured their servers and network to block certain traffic and limit access and create whitelists. This is no different to any other database cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can best decide this by forking your current code-base and clone the environment.

Then start with the implementation of the alternative data-store.

You already name certain points you want to look into, so take care of these one after the other.

You will then experience if the way you outlined/prospected the change would actually work or not and with which price that comes.

Keep a worklog in which you write down the steps you do and what your experiences are.